# How to manage logs' preservation period using RollingFlatFileTraceListener on Enterprise Library Logging Application Block?

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, enterprise, enterprise-library-5, logging-application-block

Enterprise Library(v5.0) Logging Application Block's Rolling Flat File Trace Listener has options to roll over the log files.
( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664768(v=pandp.50)#trace_rolling )

They are 'Time' and 'File Size'.

- I can manage log files' whole size by controlling 'Max Archived Files' and 'RollSizeKB'.
- Or, I can manage log files' max preservation period by controlling 'Max Archived Files' and 'RollInterval'.

But, I want to manage both log files' max preservation period and whole size at the same time.

How can I do it? 
Do I need to make and use my own TraceListener?

Comment: Yes, I think you will have to create your own TraceListener.